# Ember.js - Code is working with 0.9.5 but not 1.0.pre

Tags: ember.js

I try to figure out why the following fiddle doesn't work with `ember.js 1.0.pre` while `0.9.5` works.

#### Version 0.9.5 (working)

http://jsfiddle.net/tPfNQ/1/

#### Version 1.0.pre (not working)

http://jsfiddle.net/hSzrZ/1/

I know that `handlebars.js` is not included in the latest build of `ember.js` and i have to include it by my own.

Here is the code i'm using:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view Ember.Button target="Welcome.booksController" action="loadBooks"}}
        Load Books
    {{/view}}

    {{#collection contentBinding="Welcome.booksController"}}
        <i>Genre: {{content.genre}}</i>
    {{/collection}}
</script>


Welcome = Ember.Application.create();

Welcome.Book = Ember.Object.extend({
    title: '',
    author: '',
    genre: ''
});

var data = [ { "title": "Ready Player One", "author": "Ernest Cline", "genre": "Science Fiction" }, { "title": "Starship Troopers", "author": "Robert Heinlein", "genre": "Science Fiction" }, { "title": "Delivering Happiness", "author": "Tony Hsieh", "genre": "Business" } ];

Welcome.booksController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    loadBooks: function(){
        var self = this;
        data.forEach(function(item){
            self.pushObject(Welcome.Book.create(item));
        });
    }
});​
```

Source is: http://www.andymatthews.net/read/2012/03/07/Getting-Started-With-EmberJS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the most common issue people have with upgrading to 1.0.

The default view context has now changed to be the `context` of the view rather than the view itself.
So to access a value from the view's content you need to specify it via `view.content.xxx`.

```
{{#collection contentBinding="Welcome.booksController"}}
    <i>Genre: {{view.content.genre}}</i>
{{/collection}}
```

In this particular case you could also use the `#each` helper if you wanted.

```
{{#each Welcome.booksController}}
    <i>Genre: {{genre}}</i>
{{/each}}
```

I think there is talk of changing the `#collection` helper to work similarly.

Comment: Thanks! That's it... But i really wonder why i couldn't find anything about this problem.

Comment: I've read this post but i doesn't know what heck is the view context. Now i do :)